# Jersey (Jax-RS) & EL

Tags: java, rest, jersey, el

im trying to get a controller to return a view through a Expression Language-Filter, but have no idea on how to get jersey to use EL for filtering a view.

View with EL-tags:

```
<html>
    <title>%{msg}</title>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public Response viewEventsAsHtml(){
    String view=null;
    try {
        view=getViewAsString("events");
    }catch(IOException e){
        LOG.error("unable to load view from file",e);
        return null;
    }
    Response.ResponseBuilder builder=Response.ok(view, MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    return builder.build();
}
```

How would one go about in order to get the controller to replace the ${msg} part in the view by some arbitrary value?

Comment: JSTL? How does [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) come into the picture? Don't you mean EL, Expression Language, those `${}` things in the average JSP page? Or maybe just "output formatting" with `{n}` as you would do with `MessageFormat` API?

Comment: true.. EL is the part im interested in. so ill rephrase the question... thanks for clarification. Although it would be nice to be able to use the tags from JSTL as well (e.g.: c:... and fmt:...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Jersey then it provides the ability to return a Viewable from the Resource which will [process](http://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/mvcj) jsp by default.

Example Jersey Resource

```
@Path("/patient")
public class PatientResource {
    @GET @Path("/{patientId}") @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable view(@PathParam("patientId") int patientId) {
        return new Viewable("/patient.jsp", Integer.toString(patientId));
    }
}
```

Example patient.jsp

```
<span>${it}</span>
```

NOTE: Jersey maps the object you pass to the Viewable as "it" in the jsp.

Once you have Jersey forwarding to the jsp then you just need to add an EL [implementation](http://commons.apache.org/el/api/index.html) to your application server or servlet container.

Comment: I know this was over a year ago, but could you clarify what you mean by adding an implementation? Do you mean add the dependency jars. If so, how would you use it after the import?